# Program chrases after deleting the int value from a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a project in Visual Studios 2015 (Visual c#).
I have a **textbox** in which is introduced a number beetween 0 and 11.So if the number isn't beetween 0 and 11 or in the `textbox1` is introduced a char or string  value, a Message Box will pop up saying that the value introduced  it's incorrect.
But , if I delete the numbers from the `textbox1` or introduce a char character ,press space - the application chrases.

### Here is the code :

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            if (textBox1.Text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
            }
            else
                if (a < 0 || a > 11)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
            }
        }
```

I need to find a method that doesn't crashes when I introduce a char or string value ,or a number that isn't between 0 and 11.
(the numbers introduced in the `textbox1` are always int)

Comment: textBox1.Text = "" or textBox1.Clear()

Comment: You better use int.TryParse this will return true if `a` is a valid int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app crashes because you are trying to convert `TextBox.Text` value to `int` and it is possible that this value cannot be converted to `int` so, you get exception. If this value is non-number or empty string then `Convert.ToInt32()` crashes (throws exception and this exception in not handled - crash).

In your case it will be better to use `int.TryParse()` method instead of `Convert.ToInt32()` - if `int.TryParse()` returns `true` then it is number and you can check if value is in needed range, if `int.TryParse()` returns `false` then value cannot be parsed to `int`(it is some non-digit string):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    int a;
    bool parsed = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);

    if (!parsed || a < 0 || a > 11)
    {        
        MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int a;
                int = 0;
            try
            {
                a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            }
            catch(Exception exc){
               MessageBox.Show("incorrect exception thrown");
            }
                if (textBox1.Text == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
                }
                else
                    if (a < 0 || a > 11)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
                }
            }
```

The try parse equivelant:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    int a;
                    bool succes = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
                    if(!succes)
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
                       return;
                    }
                    if (a < 0 || a > 11)
                    {
                      MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
                    }
                    // ... Do stuff to a?
                }
```

Comment: Why solve this with exceptions? It gives a performance cost and the problem can easily be fixed with TryParse

Comment: it's not elegant. It's better to use int.TryParse method

Comment: Fair enough. Try parse is acceptable aswell. Likely better. But it solved the problem did it not?

Comment: @MortenBork It solves the problem but it's better to solve this in the preffered way (with TryParse)

Comment: @MortenBork it doesn't, your code doesn't even compile mate

Comment: @MistyK I just wrote it off the top of my head. If there is a minor syntax error I apoligize. I didn't feel like starting up my compiler to make sure. What exception do you get from your compiler?

Comment: @MortenBork use this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ . At a first glance int a; a="" won't compile due to type ambiguity

Comment: @KistyK Yeah, I removed it. I just couldn't remember if you were allowed to leave it undeclared. You are.

Comment: @MortenBork it's still won't compile. Just initialize it with -1

Comment: @MistyK set it 0. not it runs. Tested it. 

It's a bit annoying that it actually catches the - as a character.

Answer (score -1):

Your conversion is not correct

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        bool result= int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
        if (textBox1.Text == null || res)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
        }
        else
            if (a < 0 || a > 11)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("incorrect");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use result, not textBox1.Text == null condition